# Are there humans or creatures outside earth?

Tags: quran, alien

is there statement about creature or human outside earth in holy Quran ? if we can travel to outside earth, is Islam apply to that person or only human in earth ? so if human exist in other planet earth like center to Islam such us praying facing or look at sky (to earth) (ka'bah) ?

Comment: Also duplicate of "[Praying out from Earth](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/10694/9123)" and see also: "[What is the significance of facing the Kabbah during prayer when the Earth is round?](http://islam.stackexchange.com/q/376/9123)"

Answer (score 2):

Some scholars understand from the following verse that there exist seven earths as well:

> اللَّـهُ الَّذِي خَلَقَ سَبْعَ سَمَاوَاتٍ وَمِنَ الْأَرْضِ **مِثْلَهُنَّ**
>
> It is God who created the seven heavens and **the same number of** earths. [65:12](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.wahiduddin/65:12)

Other similar translations are:

1. Allah is He Who created seven Firmaments and of the earth *a similar
   number*. [Yusuf Ali](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.yusufali/65:12)
2. It is God who has created the seven heavens and *a like number of
   earths*.  [Sarwar](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.sarwar/65:12)
3. It is Allah who has created seven heavens, and *of the earth [a
   number] similar to them*. [Qarai](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.qarai/65:12)
4. It is Allah Who has created seven heavens and *of the earth the like
   thereof (i.e. seven)*. [Hilali & Khan](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.hilali/65:12)
5. It is Allah Who has created the seven heavens, *and seven earthly
   worlds like them*. [Ahmed Raza Khan](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.ahmedraza/65:12)

**مِثْلَهُنَّ** literally means **like them** but since سَمَاوَاتٍ are not similar to الْأَرْضِ in their make as we know it, the translators were compelled to believe that the Quran is equating their number.

This, however, does not explicitly endorse the existence of aliens there. We can only argue like this: Since the most distinguishing feature of earth is life, other earths may have some form of life too.

Answer (score 1):

Well AFAIK most scholars will say there are no aliens (Creatures outside earth).

But a few years ago i read a booklet of Idriss Kharchaf إدريس الخرشاف a a Moroccan university mathematics teacher in which he gave new translations or interpretations to some Verses of the Quran! According to his interpretation Quran doesn't exclude that their are cosmic creatures (animal, beasts and plants). You can read more in my Answer [here](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/20573/islam-and-alien-mages/20575#20575)

The Hanafi madhab is one of the few sunni madhabs which allows Fatwas about speculative cases: So this school already has an answer for people who will have to pray outside the earth (at least for the qiblah) it would be the actual direction of earth!

Answer (score -1):

In the absence of having a direct and clear evidence from the Quran, there is a logical answer to this question.
In Quran, we have everything we need to live, however in Quran, the only specified relations are relations between us (humans) and other humans, angels, jin and animals.
So there can not be another race, or at least no direct or indirect contact