# Do you believe in aliens?

Tags: quran, hadith, alien

1. What is the right concept of aliens in Islam?
2. Should we believe in aliens or not?
3. Do they exist according to Quran and Hadith?

#### N.B

In [stack overflow servey](https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/so-2016), I have to answer the question in the tittle.

Comment: @Sayyid that means you are telling jinns are aliens?

Comment: I would use this ayah as proof for possible life outside our own: "Among His signs is the creation of the heavens and the earth and whatever creatures He has scattered in them, and He is able to gather them whenever He wishes." (Quran 42:29)

Comment: Depends on how you define aliens. If you consider jinns aliens, then they're mentioned a lot. If you mean intelligent creatures in another planets, there is no direct mention in Quran nor Hadith of their existence. But also there is no mention of them not existing too.

Comment: @onlyforthis So, what would you write in the question in the form mentioned in the question? You have to came up with binary solution. Just Yes/No.

Comment: @manetsus Do you mean the question "**Do you believe in aliens?**"?

Comment: @onlyforthis absolutely right you are!

Comment: @manetsus Please check the answer below.

Comment: Maybe relevant http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/are-there-humans-or-creatures-outside-earth

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there is no direct mention in Quran nor Hadith of the existence of an intelligent life in other planets. But also there is no mention of them not existing too. Although some scholars interpret some verses as a possible proof such as the one Sayyid mentioned in the comments.

**Note**:The next paragraphs are totally from my own perspective and my personal opinion. Please don't consider them a fatwa.

From my own point of view as a muslim, There are two reasons that make me believe such thing. Either it is in Quran or Hadith(which what you're looking for) or if it's a scientific fact or  something sensible and perceptual that can't be denied. So not having information in Quran and Hadith gives me The choice to believe what I think it's true.

I personally Don't at all deny the possibility of the existence of intelligent beings in this massive universe. But at the same time I don't have any evidence that makes me say they 100% exist. This last paragraph would be my answer to the question.

I would like to know what you think.

Comment: I have to give one determined answer, **Yes/No**

Comment: @manetsus There is "**Other**" other section in the survey. However, I think it is up to you now, not to me. You're the one who's filling the survey. What do you think? Based on your knowledge and personal opinion, do you think aliens exist?

Comment: Once I listened to a scholar and he told that there is mentioned according to Quran and Hadith that a similar nation like human is living somewhere around the earth. But it was far ago, so he is now out of my network. That's why I am asking someone has that evidences or not. On the contrary, **relating the matter of Jins with Alien seems illogical to me**. This is quite simple. Jins are invisible, but aliens are not. @onlyforthis

Comment: @manetsus Could you please give me the link of that scholar's talk? Regarding the visibility of aliens, there is no way to prove that. They might be visible and they might be not. They might be way more sophisticated than us. They might have different ways of communication other than our known senses, even a whole different concept of life. I'm sorry if I started to play with your head, but this is how deep I go when thinking about things like that.

Comment: I told you that I lost him and he is now out of my network. If he was, then I would not post this here! Your thinking is not bad in my sense.

Comment: As @onlyforthis said. This is not a yes/no question.