# Does the Quran support other unknown life?

Tags: quran, life, universe, alien

Does anything in Hadiths or Quran or otherwise directly (or indirectly, I suppose) support intelligent life in this universe, besides humans [if they can even be considered "intelligent"]?

Comment: You mean, *besides* Jinn?

Comment: Relevant posts about other creations in the universe: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/29364/do-you-believe-in-aliens?noredirect=1&lq=1 and http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/are-there-humans-or-creatures-outside-earth (as some are marked as duplicate you should check the linked posts as well).