# Islamic perception of life beyond Earth

Tags: islamic-philosophy, life, universe

Islam clearly mentions how life(humans/animals) was formed in [Quran](http://www.scienceislam.com/evolution_creation.php):

> And Allah has Created every animal from water; of them are some creeping on their bellies; some walk on two legs; and some on four. Allah Creates what He wills: for sure Allah has Power over all things.
>   [Noble Quran 24:45]

while the stages of creation of Life were also defined in [Quran](https://quran.com/71/14-19):

> وَقَدْ خَلَقَكُمْ أَطْوَارًا
>
> While He(Allah) has created you in stages.  Quran(71:14).

I am curious to know, **if Islam specifically accepts or denies the existence of life beyond earth.**

Comment: Ofcourse it acknowledges life beyond earth, specifically the Heavenly Host ... angels, jinn, souls in paradise and on the various seven heavens, houri etc. Regarding mortal life on other planets Islam is silent about the matter ... there is nothing that specifically rejects the idea of life on other planets ... indeed there are traces of Jewish lore about seven earths and their inhabitants.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I would like you to answer the question, as why islam is silent about this matter or Does islam go parallel or against for searching life across the universe.

Comment: Islam is silent about the matter because its not important in a religious sense ... we are responsible for our actions and any life located light-years away on another planet would be responsible for their own actions.  Islam's purpose is to give us moral guidelines for daily life ... not to document the universe. Islam encourages seeking of knowledge and so I guess that it would encourage seeking life on other planets.

Comment: Please provide some references for your arguments.

Comment: References for which statement exactly?

Comment: It would be nice to add a reference with each of your statements(two comments) with ayat or hadith or statement of some Aalim.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54733/discussion-between-seeker-and-uma).

Comment: Here a relevant post http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/27820/are-there-humans-or-creatures-outside-earth