# What is the evidence for dispense of the prayer or the taharah if it is not possible to perform ritual purity?

Tags: salat, taharah, fatwa-explanation

In the fatwa islamweb #[135469](http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=135469) -which I used as a reference for my answer on [How could a Muslim pray from the Moon?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/10694/how-could-a-muslim-pray-from-the-moon/50110#50110-) it is said:
<sub>This is my own translation take it carefully</sub>

> فذهب جمهور العلماء إلى أن صلاة فاقد الطهورين واجبة لحرمة الوقت ولا تسقط عنه مع وجوب إعادتها عند الحنفية والشافعية، ولا تجب إعادتها عند الحنابلة، أما عند المالكية فإن الصلاة عنه ساقطة على المعتمد من المذهب أداء وقضاء.
>   The majority of scholars came to the conclusion that a person who has neither access nor ability to use any of both (ritually) cleaning objects (water and soil) is ordered due to the order of respecting the time for prayers and it isn't dispensed on him, while it is necessary to redo it (later) according the view of the Hanafis and Shafi'is, while the Hanbalis say it is not necessary to repeat it. While the Malikis say according to the established madhhab that this prayer is dispensed on him both as an actual due or as qada'.

As I believe that each view should have an evidence or proof I'm interested in the evidences of both views.
An explanation of the part of fatwa or quotes of other views would be great.